# Can I pool-mine with the default monero daemon?

Tags: mining-pools, mining

(question as in heading)

It appears there is no such option, but can I make it do so anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The daemon cannot pool mine. It generates its own block template, and has no concept of shares.

The other way is possible for some pool mining software, however.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You would need to use a cryptonote pool miner like this one:
https://github.com/nanopool/Claymore-XMR-CPU-Miner

It will connect to the pool server, and only the pool server will connect to a monero daemon.